# Use of comma WITH a conjunction

Tags: grammar

I recently started using Grammarly in some of my writing and the spell/grammar checking software seems to place a comma after just about all conjunctions. I thought that a conjunction was, sort of, like a comma in a sentence, that is, it separates a thought. So, the question is, is there some rule for when it is proper to use both a conjunction AND a comma?

Comment: A comma *after* conjunctions? A real example of what Grammarly has done would be helpful here, I think.

Comment: I think that the so-called 'Oxford' comma would be an example.

Comment: Really? If you're not sure whether commas are permitted or required after conjunctions would you mind posting, say, three examples with your own and what you can discern of Grammarly's thoughts thereon?

Comment: Comma *after*, I presume? If so, there's a difference between British and American spelling conventions here. Traditionally in British English we don't as a rule put commas after conjunctions like but, and or or. However, in US English they do. There's a clique of British English writers and style commentators who do advocate it in British English too. When used in British English, this kind of comma is often referred to as the 'Oxford comma', and people who advocate its usage secretly like the fact that it has its own snobby title, and is unconventional :) Doesn't mean they're wrong though!